# How to allow access to page in zf2 by both urls: site/page and site/page/

Tags: php, zend-framework2

SO!

I installed zfcUser module. I tried to open `site/user` link. It worked. When I try to open `site/user/` (added `/` symbol) it is not openning. Why?

I think, I have to edit router. I found this in `module.config.php` file in `\vendor\zf-commons\zfc-user\config\` directory:

```
'route' => '/user',
```

How to change this, so it will allow both `/user` and `/user/` urls?

Why it is possible to write both `/application` and `/application/`, but it is not specified in config file?:

```
'route'    => '/application',
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there are a couple of ways to make trailing slash works, one is creating a Segment type route marking the trailing slash as not mandatory, eg.

```
    'users' => array(
        'type'    => 'Segment',
        'options' => array(
            // Change this to something specific to your module
            'route'    => '/users[/]',
            'defaults' => array(
                '__NAMESPACE__' => 'Application\Controller',
                'controller'    => 'User',
                'action'        => 'index',
            ),
        ),
```

You can also add a child Literal route to another Literal route, like follow

```
    'users' => array(
        'type'    => 'Literal',
        'options' => array(
            // Change this to something specific to your module
            'route'    => '/users',
            'defaults' => array(
                '__NAMESPACE__' => 'Application\Controller',
                'controller'    => 'User',
                'action'        => 'index',
            ),
        ),
        'may_terminate' => true,
        'child_routes' => array(
            'default' => array(
                'type'    => 'Literal',
                'options' => array(
                    'route'    => '/',
                ),
            ),
        ),
    ),
```

If you want the trailing slash on user work with ZfcUser you can extend its routing rules adding this configuration in any other registered module

```
    'zfcuser' => array(
        'type' => 'Literal',
        'priority' => 1000,
        'options' => array(
            'route' => '/user',
            'defaults' => array(
                'controller' => 'zfcuser',
                'action'     => 'index',
            ),
        ),
        'may_terminate' => true,
        'child_routes' => array(
            'default' => array(
                'type' => 'Literal',
                'options' => array(
                    'route' => '/',
                ),
            ),
        ),
    ),
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I think I already tried the first way and it not worked. Can't check it again now, I will try it a bit later.

Comment: Aha! I don't know why, but 1st approach doesn't work. Don't you know why? Looks like working method, but it's not! Can you explain why? Anyway, 2nd method with adding child route worked. But! What if I have some child routes? It is an array with pairs: `key => array` where key is some name and `array` is array, representing child route. The question is what key should I use for it this child route? I tried `a` and it works. Looks like it doesn't matter. I am working with `zfcUser` at the moment.

Comment: Anyway voted up and accepted, because one of your suggestions worked! Thank you!